# iOS 9, Swift 2.1 - Delete alert in vertical layout

Tags: ios, swift

I have a plain style alert that shows 2 buttons horizontally made with the following implementation and I'd like to know how I can make it like the attached image.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This item will be deleted", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil));
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {
        alertAction in
        self.deleteItem(sender)
}))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

[image]

Comment: change  preferredStyle: .ActionSheet in code.

Comment: is your problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one :-

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This item will be deleted", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
```

Comment: I didn't expect it to be as simple as that.. nice one!

Comment: give me a few minutes until it allows me to :)

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the following for what u want to acheive**

```
@IBAction func actionRecommend(sender: UIButton) {


        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Recommend Using", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        optionMenu.view.tintColor = primaryDarkColor

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("File Facebook")
        })

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Contacts", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("File toContacts")
           // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toContacts", sender: nil)

         })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("Cancelled")
        })


        optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```